# Parameter returning not in the correct format

Tags: c#, sql, async-await

I have an async task method that queries a database table for the total amount of Credits in a specific column. I have a string parameter in the method that I use for the query to identify which user is logged in, which is stored in `Properties.Settings.Default.Student_Number;`. The column for the student number in the database is a varchar and everywhere else in my code its a string, but I'm getting an exception saying `Input string was not in correct format`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong

```
private async Task<int> Count_Credits(string student_number)
{
    int count = 0;
    string sql = "SELECT SUM(Module_Credit) AS TOTAL_CREDITS FROM Module_Data WHERE Student_Number=@num";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@num", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = student_number;
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }

    return count;
}
```

How I am calling the method

```
Task<int> count_credits = Count_Credits(Student_Number);
module_info.Total_Credits = await count_credits; //Exception Goes to this line
```

I am using binding on the label for

```
module_info.Total_Credits
```

Comment: What is the raw value being returned by `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: I don't have any values in the database as of yet, but I wouldn't even know what is returns as I get the exception before anything can return

Comment: What I want to have it returned is 0 if no data is in the table

Comment: if nothing else works, figure out in which line exactly in Count_Credits the exception occurs. Is it the int.Parse, or related to the SQL query?

Comment: The exception goes the the method with the parameter, no exception goes anywhere near the sql or parsing

Comment: Why are you using `OpenAsync`, but your query isn't using `ExecuteScalarAsync`?

Comment: @zaggler I didn't even notice that, I've updated the code accordingly

Comment: @PureWare Well, the error goes to the method call, because there is an exception being thrown inside the method. Dotnet can be a bit vague as to where exactly an exception occured. If it just gives you a method, you might want to find out which line in that method caused the exception. Just for future debugging reference. The other answers seem to be in agreement the call to int.Parse is the issue due to the parameter being invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result returned by `ExecuteScalar` will either be an `int` or be `null`. Also, making a round-trip via string is not necessary. But we must check for `null`.

Pattern matching was introduced in recent versions of C#, allowing terser code in many situations:

```
count = cmd.ExecuteScalar() is int i ? i : 0;
```

If the scalar is a boxed `int` object, it will be cast to `int` and assigned to the new variable `i` and the result of the `is` expression will be `true`. We use this result in a ternary expression to determine the final result.

---

Yet another possibility:

```
count = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() as int?) ?? 0;
```

The operator `as` casts the input to the desired type if the cast is successful and otherwise returns `null`. Therefore the target type must be nullable. Hence we specify `int?` (= `Nullable<int>`) as target type. We use the null coalescing operator `??` to convert `null` to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check if a result is returned from `ExecuteScalar` before you can cast the type.

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
{
  count = (int)result;
}
```

For a more terse check, use pattern matching (per Olivier's comment):

```
if(cmd.ExecuteScalar() is int i) 
{ 
  count = i; 
}
```

Also, you should `await` the method itself when getting the value:

```
int count_credits = await Count_Credits(Student_Number);
module_info.Total_Credits = count_credits;
```

Comment: Does it make it a difference where I put the await

Comment: TBH this should be fixed in the query itself. User mentioned: `What I want to have it returned is 0 if no data is in the table` which can be easily done by changing the query.

Comment: or with pattern matching `if(cmd.ExecuteScalar() is int i) { count = i; }`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - agreed. Just didn't want to go into something more advanced.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Can You post your comment as answer please